# image not displaying on the navbar with django include tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a nav.html template,css.html template and js.html template. then i used the include template tag to render them in my base.html template.

(nav.html)

```
 {% load staticfiles %}

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary py-1">
             <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">
               <img src="{% static 'profiles/logo.png' %}" width="30"      height="30" class='d-inline-block align-top' alt=""/>Hot-Minet Services Ltd
             </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

(css.html)

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

(js.html)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(base.html)

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

{% include "snippets/css.html" %}

<title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
{% include "snippets/nav.html" %}
<br>
    {% block form %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
           <div class="col-sm-6">   
              <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.as_p }}
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
               </form>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% include "snippets/js.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

(home.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block form %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
          <form action="/update/slug/" method="GET">
                <input class="pt-3 form-control" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Type client name here"/>
                <br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary pt-2 mb-5" type="submit" value="Update"/>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>   
{% endblock %}
```

(settings.py)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static' 'static-alone')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static' 'media')
    STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static" 'profiles'),

]
```

(urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from profiles.views import(
    home,
    SendMail,
    Add,
    resultsPageView,
    profileUpdate,
)

urlpatterns = [
    #
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/',home),
    url(r'^SendMail/', SendMail.as_view(), name='SendMail'),
    url(r'^Add/', Add.as_view(), name='Add'),
    url(r'^results/', resultsPageView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', profileUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns  +=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns  += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

everything is working fine but the logo in the navbar does not display can someone identify what am doing wrong here Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured your static files?

Comment: Yes i have done that on my settings.py file and also on my urls.py file.

Comment: Once check your file path in settings, also configure image path in settings and inspect what url you are getting in your <img> tag

Comment: Did the inspect and the url am getting is the same with my <img> tag

Comment: finally i found my error the static directory was not in the same directory of my app